Can I charge HP Pavilion - 15-cs3001ne with a Type-C plugin. Type-C to PIN converter
I have an HP Pavilion - 15-cs3001ne. Based on the product description @ https://support.hp.com/sk-en/document/c06522293 the type-C, what I have is only Type-C™ (Data Transfer Only, 5 Gb/s signaling rate)...
Now I want to buy an external Power Station to be able to charge my laptop when there is no electricity available. here is the power station I want to buy https://www.amazon.com/JOYROOM-75000mAh-Retractable-Multicolor-Compatible/dp/B0D1BWJ5C7 .
Can I charge my laptop using this type of power stations? using a plugin convertor for example? Which can convert Type-C to smart PIN? Or is this not possible?

Yes. With this: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09TZKM847
USB PD can output several different voltages. You need something that has a chip in it that can handle the communication to the power station to tell it you want 20V out. Then you need to put that 20V on a barrel jack. The above product will do that for you.
Note, newer laptops can be powered with a USB-C to USB-C cable directly from the power station to the laptop, but the HP Pavilion - 15-cs3001ne is too old to have that capability. You will need to use the adapter as this computer only charges through the barrel jack.

thanks a lot for the useful reply. i checked with the vendor of the power station, and they mentioned that their product is not compatible with https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09TZKM847 although based on my reading and understanding it should work..

I would expect that is just them not wanting to give official approval. Any device that is using USB-C PD charging has to use the same set of voltages and the same communication protocol to decide those voltages. This product claims to use USB PD on the amazon page. If you use more than 1 charging port, the referenced station will drop down to 65W charging (which is still 20V but perhaps this dongle is not smart enough to deal with the lower current draw). In any case, if it doesn't work, it is required to shut down safely and refuse to charge.
